# } Expected in Routine

Tags: c#

I'm a student currently learning C#. I tried writing this routine but I get an error which tells me that a "}" is expected. However when I add the "}" I get a whole lot of other errors. I presume it's because you don't add a "}" before an "else" statement. This is my code:

```
private void PathExist()
{
    if (Directory.Exists(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + @"\"))
        lblExist.Visible = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTime = false;
        // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
        MainFrm MainForm = new MainFrm();
        MainForm.Show();
        Hide();//This is where Visual Studio is telling me that a "}" is expected
    else
    {
        lblExist.Visible = true;
        lblExist.Text = "Folder doesn't exist";
        lblExist.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio is Correct, you do not have  a closing bracket on your if statement. Put it in and compile. The other errors should be fixed.

Comment: If Visual Studio tells you that a '}' is expected... then a '}' is expected :P

Comment: If block needs `{` at the start and `}` at the end, after `Hide();`

Comment: C# is not Python. You may want to read on syntax more carefully and pay attention to the fact that whitepsaces are not significant.

Comment: don't forget `if{}`

Comment: Hit `tab` twice after you wrote `if` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learning how to format code is a CRITICAL skill for writing code that works correctly.

```
private void PathExist()
{
    if (Directory.Exists(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + @"\"))
    {
        lblExist.Visible = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTime = false;
        // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
        MainFrm MainForm = new MainFrm();
        MainForm.Show();
        Hide(); //This is where Visual Studio is telling me that a "}" is expected
    }        
    else 
    {
        lblExist.Visible = true;
        lblExist.Text = "Folder doesn't exist";
        lblExist.ForeColor = Color.Red;

    }
}
```

Note how an opening `{` has been added immediately after the if statement, with a corresponding closing `}` right before the else.

Now, you might claim "but I've seen code in C# where the braces appear optional!"  That is only applicable to single logical lines like the following:

```
if (condition)
    ExecuteMethod();
else 
    ExecuteOtherMethod();
```

If any block of code within a condition is more than one "instruction", you must wrap that code in enclosing braces.  In addition, some C# developers will insist that ALL code should ALWAYS be wrapped in braces to avoid confusion and as a matter of good practice.

Comment: Not to mention, VS has the "wonderful" habit of auto-inserting a close bracket for every open bracket you type. It does the work for you. Don't delete one unless you add one somewhere else, and you'll be golden.

Comment: @Niko happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  DO you want all the statements between the if and the else to be executed only if the Directory Exists? If so, then you need to put them all in a block. And since the block has more than one statement, it must be designated with opening and closing braces. Otherwise, the if will only include the next statement .

```
        private void PathExist()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + @"\"))
        {
            lblExist.Visible = false;
            Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTime = false;
            // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
            MainFrm MainForm = new MainFrm();
            MainForm.Show();
            Hide(); 
        }
        else 
        {
            lblExist.Visible = true;
            lblExist.Text = "Folder doesn't exist";
            lblExist.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        }
    }
```

If you only want the `lblExist.Visible = false;` statement to be executed when the `Directory.Exists`, and you want the next 4 statements to *always* execute,  then you need to explain what the `else` is for. Because it's not part of the if clause. The `if` clause, as you had it, ends with the semicolon after the `lblExist.Visible = false;`  You can't put other code intended to always execute between the `if` block and the `else` block of an `if/else` construction. That's what is generating your error.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include {} after IF statement, only one statement under the IF condition will be considered as in the if Block. And your else block don't have a If condition associated to it.

Compiler assumed it to be

```
private void PathExist()
{
    if (Directory.Exists(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + @"\"))
    {
        lblExist.Visible = false;
    }
        Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTime = false;
        // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
        MainFrm MainForm = new MainFrm();
        MainForm.Show();
        Hide();


    else
    {
        lblExist.Visible = true;
        lblExist.Text = "Folder doesn't exist";
        lblExist.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Else block is not valid.
This can be solved as below.

```
private void PathExist()
{
    if (Directory.Exists(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + @"\"))
    {//Answer
        lblExist.Visible = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTime = false;
        // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
        MainFrm MainForm = new MainFrm();
        MainForm.Show();
        Hide();
    }//Answer
    else
    {
        lblExist.Visible = true;
        lblExist.Text = "Folder doesn't exist";
        lblExist.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```